# PSExec error al mandar argumentos al equipo remoto

Tags: c#, cmd

Tengo la siguiente instruccion en CMD y usando PSExec para mandar ejecutar un proceso en una maquina de forma remota pero siempre me regresa que esta mal el password o el  usuario.
Ya verifique y ambos son correctos ya que con esos entro como administrador

```html
C:\Users\juan\Downloads\PSTools>PSExec.exe \\192.168.0.1 -u SUPERUSUARIO -p 12345 -i E:\carpeta\Launcher.exe

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


PsExec could not start E:\carpeta\Launcher.exe on 192.168.0.1:
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Mi idea es hacer que funcione en CMD y luego pasarlo a C#, o si tiene algun ejemplo en C# tambien ayudaria, yo tengo lo siguiente pero no me ejecuta nada en la maquina remota.

```html
string server = "192.168.0.1";
                ProcessStartInfo startRecol = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startRecol.FileName = @"C:\Users\juan\Downloads\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
                startRecol.Arguments = @"\\" + server + @" -u SUPERUSUARIO -p 12345 -i E:\carpeta\Launcher.exe";
                startRecol.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startRecol.UseShellExecute = false;
                
                 Process.Start(startRecol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui mi solucion:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
try
        {
            
            string server = "NameServer or IP";
            ProcessStartInfo startRecol = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startRecol.FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"PSExec.exe");
            startRecol.Arguments = @" -s -d \\" + server + @" -u na\UserName -p password -i D:\carpeta\LauncherPoll.bat";
            startRecol.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startRecol.UseShellExecute = false;
             Process p = Process.Start(startRecol);
             p.WaitForExit();
            
              MessageBox.Show("Ejecucion terminada con exito");
           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

Tratare de emplicar el codigo que es poco pero me ayudo a solucionar mi problema presentado.
en la variable server asigno el nombre del servidor o la IP, despues inciailizamos processstartinfo en la propieda Filename cargamos desde la ruta donde inicia la aplicacion el PSExec.exe, yo decidi copir a la carpeta raiz el exe y la ruta la obtengo con Path.Combine, en la propiedad Arguments agrego el usuario y password con el que se ejecutar el proceso esto es muy importante debe de tener permisos de administrador el usuario, tambien pasamos la ruta del .bat y el nombre del server.
Con process.start() mandamos a ejecutar el proceso en el servidor y listo!!

Espero que a alguien mas le ayude.

Saludos.